# elastic search returning no results filtering on multi value field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field in the elastic search called category and it contains multiple values. Below are the sample values

```
"category": [
                    "Commercial",
                    "CafeBarRestaurant",
                    "Tables"
                ],
```

Now I am querying the elasticsearch to get the document where the category is "Commercial". Below is my query:

```
{
 "from":0,
 "size":40,
 "query":{
  "bool":{
     "filter":[
        {
           "bool":{
              "must":[
                 {
                    "term":{
                       "category":{
                          "value":"Commercial",
                          "boost":1.0
                       }
                    }
                 }
              ],
              "adjust_pure_negative":true,
              "boost":1.0
           }
        }
     ],
     "adjust_pure_negative":true,
     "boost":1.0
  }
```

}
}
Mapping:

```
{
"products": {
    "mappings": {
        "category": {
            "full_name": "category",
            "mapping": {
                "category": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Every time it is giving me empty results. Can anyone suggest to me what wrong in the query.
Thanks.

Comment: your query Commerical is not Commercial

Comment: typo in the request adding the ticket. With the matching value, it is giving zero results

Comment: change your query by example from here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html   I thin issue is with bool filter and bool must sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need bool. try:

```
{
  "query: {
      "match": {
          "category": "Commercial"}}  }
```

or:

```
{
  "query: {
      "term": {
          "category.keyword": "Commercial"}}  }
```

Comment: I also need to add few more filters on aggregations so I am using bool

Comment: could you please post you index mapping?